# How to get a list of services programmatically in Symfony?

Tags: php, symfony

I want to have a list of services and class names in my web application. I can use this command in console:

```
php bin/console debug:container
```

And I get something like this:

```
Symfony Container Public Services
=================================

 -------------------------------------------------------------------- --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  Service ID                                                           Class name
 -------------------------------------------------------------------- --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  annotation_reader                                                    Doctrine\Common\Annotations\CachedReader
  app.annotations.softdelete.driver                                    AppBundle\Doctrine\SoftDelete\Mapping\Driver\Annotation
  app.annotations.translate.driver                                     AppBundle\Doctrine\Mapping\Driver\TranslateDriver
  app.be_auth_controller.listener                                      AppBundle\EventListener\BeAuthControllerListener
```

I want to have this information on a web page using Symfony 3.

I created a service and I used:

```
$this->container->getServiceIds();
```

which returns something like:

```
[
  0 => "service_container"
  1 => "annotation_reader"
  2 => "annotations.reader"
  3 => "app.annotations.softdelete.driver"
  4 => "app.annotations.translate.driver"
...
]
```

I don't know, how to get the class names.

In any cases works this:

```
get_class($this->container->get($this->container->getServiceIds()[1]))
```

But in some other cases it throws different exceptions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get full definition of given service you can use ContainerBuilder and Symfony cache file.

first create instance of ContainerBuilder:

```
$container = new ContainerBuilder();
```

then load cache file:

```
$cachedFile = $this->container->getParameter('debug.container.dump');
$loader = new XmlFileLoader($container, new FileLocator());
$loader->load($cachedFile);
```

now you can get full definition of your service like this:

```
$definition = $container->getDefinition('service_name')
$definition->getClass();
```

Comment: This only works with debug on (i.e., in the dev environment), which severely limits its utility.

Answer (score 3):

Your attempt with `get_class` is what came to mind as I was reading it, but whatever errors you are getting will come from improper fetching of those services.  After all when you call `$container->get(...)`, its at that moment instantiating those classes.

To be honest the output you are looking to replicate can be reproduced based on the method used by that command.

https://github.com/symfony/framework-bundle/blob/master/Command/ContainerDebugCommand.php

You'll just need to adapt it to work for you.